# how to make clients dynamically authenticate mqtt broker by using their own credential

Tags: spring-integration, mqtt, iot

Here is the code for  authentication to the mqtt broker by mqtt-spring integration,

```
public DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory clientfactory() {

    DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory factory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
    MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
    options.setUserName("username");
    options.setPassword("password".toCharArray());
    options.setServerURIs(new String[] { "tcp://localhost:1883" });
    factory.setConnectionOptions(options);

    return factory;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttOutboundChannel")
public MqttPahoMessageHandler mqqtMessageHandler() {

    MqttPahoMessageHandler handler = new MqttPahoMessageHandler("clientId", clientfactory());
    handler.setAsync(true);
    handler.setDefaultQos(2);
    handler.setDefaultRetained(true);
    return handler;
}
```

Suppose I am using many clients for publishing data to their own set of topics.And I am supposed to assign unique authentication credentials to each client for establishing mqtt broker connection.I think the above code allows only one set of credentials, even if we use many clients.Is it possible to make dynamic ?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to replace the `DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory` with your own implementation of `MqttPahoClientFactory`; perhaps a subclass of `DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory`.